# A counter example of the direct sum of sub spaces.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, direct-sum

I was asked to give examples of $3$ subspaces where $W + V + U$ is not the direct sum of these $3$ subspaces. $W$, $V$, and $U$ are subspaces of a vector space, just to clarify.

I am having trouble finding out whether or not the intersection of the vectors is the zero vector or not. For example, if i take the $3$ subspaces $W = (1,0,1)$, $V = (1,1,0)$, $U = (2,3,1)$, then $W + U + V$ is $(3,4,2)$. Would this be also be a direct sum? or not? I dont think it would. How do i check that their intersection is not the zero vector?

But if i took for example $W = (1,0,1)$, $V = (0, 6, 0)$, this would be a direct sum right?

What if i took $W = (1,0,1)$, $V = (0, 6, 0)$ and $U = (2, 3, 2)$, would this be a direct sum or not? Is it because i could write $U$ as $0.5 V + 2W$ ? Does the direct sum have to do with linear dependance?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $W$ a subspace or a vector?  Which subspace is described by $(1,0,1)$? Can you write out the definitions (as given by your textbook or class-notes) of a "sum" of vector spaces and that of a "direct sum"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes W U and V are subspaces of a vector space .

Comment: So what "subspace" is $(1,0,1)$?  Do you mean the set $\{(0,1,0)\}$? this isn't a subspace.  Do you mean the subspace generated by $(1,0,1)$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes i mean the subspace generated by (1,0,1)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom  What about W = {(a, a, 0) | a ∈ R}, U = {(0, b, b) | b ∈ R}, and V = span ((2, 3, 1)). as well? How would i know if this was a direct sum or not?

Comment: Yes, those are indeed the subspaces generated by the vectors you've listed. Now, I'd still like for you to write out (or provide a link to) the definition of a sum and of a direct sum that you happen to be using, please.

Comment: Also, a common notation for what you'd like to say is $W = \langle (1,1,0) \rangle$, meaning "$W$ is the subspace spanned by the vector $(1,1,0)$".